# Error deleting articles by ID "Cannot DELETE /author/1"

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express, ejs

In my blogging web application using Express.js and SQLite authors manage articles. I have a `draftArticles` table in database. I display a list of draft articles with options to edit and delete. I'm using Express.js templates for rendering views and Express.js for handling routes. When I click a delete button I receive:

> Cannot DELETE /author/1

There might be an issue with how article ID's are connected. The delete button is in a form and I'm using the method-override library to add a DELETE method. In my route I'm using `req.params.id` to retrieve article ID and perform deletion:

```
router.delete("/:id", (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.id;

    // Delete the draft article from the database
    global.db.run("DELETE FROM draftArticles WHERE id = ?", [id], function (err) {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
        } else {
            res.redirect("/author/home");
        }
    });
});
```

home.ejs that includes the delete buttons:

```
<h2 class="mt-4">Draft Articles</h2>
<table class="mb-4">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Subtitle</th>
      <th>Created</th>
      <th>Last Modified</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% draftArticles.forEach(function(article) { %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= article.title %></td>
        <td><%= article.subtitle %></td>
        <td><%= article.created %></td>
        <td><%= article.last_modified %></td>
        <td>
            <a href="/author/drafts/<%= article.id %>" class="btn btn-secondary">Edit Article</a>
            <form action="/author/<%= article.id %>?_method=DELETE" method="post" class="d-inline">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% }); %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I verified article ID's in database and template. How to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO :) Did you check what network request (Network section of developer tools of browser) goes out, when you run click Delete button on UI. Does the method match? Is the URL correct? Do you get any response body with errors?

Comment: thank you, Kartoos. I do get an error in the network tab when I click the button. Turns out the method I'm using is correct. However, in the index.js, i should call app.use(methodOverride) before using the router. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

in the index.js, i should call app.use(methodOverride) before using the router.

```
//this uses the library method-override to add a delete method to forms
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
//this adds all the userRoutes to the app under the path /user
app.use('/user', userRoutes);
```